# Twitter-python script no error but not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been trying to get this script to output a sequence of status instances. I want the text output saved to a file, is that possible?  Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance! :)

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='int',
                      consumer_secret='int',
                      access_token_key='int',
                      access_token_secret='int')


def GetUserTimeline(self,
                        user_id=111554559,
                        screen_name='Enhedslisten',
                        since_id=None,
                        max_id=783373235568214016,
                        count=200,
                        include_rts=True,
                        trim_user=True,
                        exclude_replies=True):

        url = '%s/statuses/user_timeline.json' % (self.base_url)
        parameters = {}

        if user_id:
            parameters['user_id'] = enf_type('user_id', int, user_id)
        elif screen_name:
            parameters['screen_name'] = screen_name
        if since_id:
            parameters['since_id'] = enf_type('since_id', int, since_id)
        if max_id:
            parameters['max_id'] = enf_type('max_id', int, max_id)
        if count:
            parameters['count'] = enf_type('count', int, count)

        parameters['include_rts'] = enf_type('include_rts', bool, include_rts)
        parameters['trim_user'] = enf_type('trim_user', bool, trim_user)
        parameters['exclude_replies'] = enf_type('exclude_replies', bool, exclude_replies)

        resp = self._RequestUrl(url, 'GET', data=parameters)
        data = self._ParseAndCheckTwitter(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))

        return [Status.NewFromJsonDict(x) for x in data]
```

Comment: What is the type of `Status.NewFromJsonDict(element)` ? You might need to pickle it instead of writing it into a file

Comment: Would that be like this? pickle.dump[Status.NewFromJsonDict(x) for x in data]

Comment: Or like this? pickle.load([Status.NewFromJsonDict(x) for x in data])

Comment: no. `dump` instead of `load` and use a context manager to dump (`with open(path) as f : pickle.dump(object, f)`